# How to remove "not a GROUP BY expression" error from the statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

**The schema of the table is:**
Emp (Empno, Ename, Job, Mgr, Hiredate, Sal, Comm, Deptno)

Question:

> Display the job, deptno and average salary of employees belonging to
> department 10 or 20 and their salary is more than 2000 and average
> salary is more than 2500.

My Query:

```
SELECT Job, Deptno, AVG(Sal) "AVGSALARY"
FROM Emp
WHERE Sal > 2000 AND Deptno IN(10, 20)
GROUP BY Job
HAVING AVG(Sal) > 2500;
```

**Error:**
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

I cannot find what is wrong I am doing here that makes this error appear.
I am using the same column name in the `GROUP BY` statement that I have mentioned in the `SELECT` statement.
Also, the aggregate function I used in the `HAVING` statement is also present in the `SELECT` statement.

My question is 'how can I remove this error from this statement?'.
Any performance improvement query is also welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include all the non-aggregated columns in the GROUP BY statement. So include Deptno in the GROUP BY as well:

```
SELECT Job, Deptno, AVG(Sal) "AVGSALARY"
FROM Emp
WHERE Sal > 2000 AND Deptno IN(10, 20)
GROUP BY Job, Deptno
HAVING AVG(Sal) > 2500;
```